# How to create a Webproject and have GWT dependant project and run the webproject in development mode in eclipse or RAD?

Tags: gwt, webproject

I have my web project MyWebProject and I have my GWT project as a dependent project.. I need to run the web project in development mode, but its not listing any entry point modules to do the same.. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks
Jugunu

Comment: Is `MyWebProject` a non-GWT dynamic web project?

Comment: I first made it a non-GWT dynamic webproject and then converted it to GWT web project, so as to run it in dev mode.

Comment: I am using eclipse for my project - I missed to add the info

Comment: Please share your code. what have you tried till now?

Comment: Apologies.. Now its working for the sample code.. But i try to use the actual project its giving me a different error...

Starting Jetty on port 0
   [WARN] Unknown realm: default
   [WARN] EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:364)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:

Comment: Add it in your original post as an edit section to make it clear for others.

Comment: My bad, i missed the error coming from web.xml... Websphere ignores it and deploys the war... but not so with jetty.. I just removed that.. Now getting other issues.. Will update if it works fine.. Thanks for offering a helping hand..